# jQuery .ajax() request sending twice in IE (at the same time, when the events were not)

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, caching

I have a lot of code that uses jQuery .ajax(). It all works fine in Firefox and Chrome however it needs to work in IE too. I have the problem in IE7 and IE9.

Sometimes the AJAX request is not sent, although the .on("change") or on.("click") event has definitely fired, as some html on the screen is displayed when these events fire. Then if I change another element which has an .ajax request tied to it I have noticed that both of the requests are received at the same time at the terminal, I'm coding in python by the way. As you can see I have caching turned off.

Here is some of my code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#view_content').on("click", function () {
        $("#loading").removeClass("invisible");
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: $SCRIPT_ROOT + '/stats',
            cache: false,
            data: {from_date: $('#from_date').val(), to_date: $('#to_date').val(), option: $('#drop_down_3 option:selected').html()},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                $("#stats").html(data.stats_output);
                $("#timings").html(data.timings);
                $("#view_timings").text("View Timings");
                drawChart(data.dateCounts);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('Error loading data');

            }
        })
        .done(function (data) {
            $("#loading").addClass("invisible");
        });
      });
    });
```

These are 2 sample requests output by the terminal. These were clicked seconds apart but as you can see they were received at the same time - 15:06:13

```
    2013-06-05 16:57:48,019 (12796) werkzeug INFO - 127.0.0.1 - - [05/Jun/2013 16:57:48] "GET /stats?from_date=14%2F05%2F2013&to_date=05%2F06%2F2013&option=Select+Option&_=1370447674597 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
    2013-06-05 16:57:48,020 (12796) werkzeug INFO - 127.0.0.1 - - [05/Jun/2013 16:57:48] "GET /stats?from_date=14%2F05%2F2013&to_date=05%2F06%2F2013&option=Select+Option&_=1370447674597 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: but those requests aren't even for the `/stats` page?!

Comment: Sorry I pulled the wrong example, but the code for the stats is pretty much identical as for the drop down page. Both give the same problem. Sorry for the confusion, a little bit silly of me

Comment: Updated now to show the feedback from the terminal for the stats request. Thanks!

Comment: the request log and code still don't match...

Comment: Really sorry, a long day of errors has wrecked my brain! Should be okay now.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, if you search your page for "view_content", is there only one instance?

Comment: I'm assuming you're asking if there's only one instance of this function or any other on click function for this element. Yes this is the only function attached to this element.